# Unique index with mongolite

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I see that we can add an index by simply specifying the name of the field:

```
library(mongolite)
m <- mongo()
m$index("field")
```

How do we specify a unique index? ie:

```
db.members.createIndex( { "field": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Comment: Did you figure out?

Comment: The answer is here: https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/issues/133